# Relying party vs application groups in ADFS

Tags: asp.net, authentication, adfs, adfs4.0

I am trying to understand the authentication in .NET web applications using ADFS.

I followed the example in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs) and I was able to handle the authentication of my app via ADFS. The given example adds application in a application group of adfs

Few of the examples adds replying party trust instead of application group.

I apologize if it sounds naive but I need to know the difference between these two and how it affects .NET applications

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use WS-Fed or SAML, the client is a relying party (RP).

If you use OpenID Connect / OAuth, the client is inside an application group. But functionally, it's the same as a RP.

Comment: why oauth in https://adfshelp.microsoft.com/ClaimsXray works without application group?